# Computing averages based on data in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to figure out how to accomplish this in MySQL

I have two tables:

1) Service Table:

**Serv_ID   |   Prov_ID     |   Serv_Date**

11812       |   CT18T005    |   2016-01-21

11819       | CT18T005      | 2016-02-23

11823       |   CT18T006    |   2016-01-25

11832       |   CT18T010    |       2016-01-26

11838   |       CT18T010    |       2016-02-23

11842   |   CT18T007    |       2016-01-25

11848   |       CT18T007    |       2016-02-25

12886   |       CT18T006    |       2016-02-26

12906   |       CT18T005    |       2016-04-21

12907   |       CT18T005    |       2016-04-28

12916   |       CT18T010    |       2016-03-22

12918   |       CT18T010    |       2016-03-29

12934   |       CT18T007    |       2016-04-29

13475   |       CT18T010    |       2016-06-07

2) Provider Table:

**Prov_ID       |       Prov_Start      |   Prov_End**

CT18T001        |   2016-01-01      |   2016-06-30

CT18T005        |   2016-01-01     |    2016-06-30

CT18T006        |   2016-01-01      |   2016-05-13

CT18T007        |   2016-01-01  |       2016-06-30

CT18T010        |   2016-01-15  |       2016-06-30

I need to compute the Average Service Units (ASU) provided per provider per month during the reporting period (01/01/2016 - 06/30/2016), taking into account the number of days the provider(s) were active during the month.  So, there were 4 providers active for the entire month of February.  Provider 006 was active between 01/01/2016 and 05/13/2016 and thus should be counted for the entire month of Jan - April and 13 days in May.

**Month ASU/Provider**

January |   4/(4+15/30)  |assuming 30 days in a month

February|   4/5

...

...

June

The final output will be a number (Average of the ASU/Provider per month) : Sum(ASU/Provider) / 6

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: What I'm having difficulty is in coming up with the average for active providers per month January 4.5, February 5 and so on.  I tried using the example in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090016/count-the-number-of-rows-in-30-day-bins  to apply here but was unsuccessful.

Comment: I don't see any code, or your attempt where you failed, to help you figure out what went wrong.

Comment: I've thought a lot about it, but don't know where to begin for that part of it.  - I've just managed to work out the logic.  If you can point me in the right direction I will try again.

Comment: For the first part, I have calculated the number of services by month using 

SELECT MONTH(Serv_Date), COUNT(Serv_ID) as ASU
FROM Serv
GROUP BY MONTH(Serv_Date);

I'm trying to generate a table for active providers by month from the Provider table and that is the part where I'm stuck.