# Weekly report behalf of specific date field

Tags: mysql

I am using this query for weekly reporting but can not found a way like this

```
week_number | week_startdate | organization_1 | organization_2
---------------------------------------------------------------
1           | 2013-01--05    |count(date) like 4,24,etc_ | count(date) like 4,24,etc_
```

SQL:

```
SELECT WEEK(signed_date) AS week_name, signed_date AS Week_Starting,
       YEAR(signed_date), WEEK(signed_date), COUNT(*)
FROM business
WHERE YEAR(signed_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(signed_date), '/', WEEK(signed_date))
ORDER BY YEAR(signed_date), WEEK(signed_date
```

SAMPLE DATA:

signed_date | organization_id
01-01-2013  | 1
02-01-2013 | 1
03-01-2013  | 2

In 1 week organization_1 have 2 signed & organization_2 has 1 signed.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data for the tables?

Comment: sample data edited in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use  case within count or sum:

```
SELECT WEEK(signed_date) AS week_name, signed_date AS Week_Starting,
       YEAR(signed_date), WEEK(signed_date),
SUM(CASE  WHEN organization_id=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as organization_1,
SUM(CASE WHEN organization_id=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as organization_2
FROM business
WHERE YEAR(signed_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(signed_date), '/', WEEK(signed_date))
ORDER BY YEAR(signed_date), WEEK(signed_date);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/587ad/3

Comment: I have another question related to your answer. Is any option to show also those week which has no transaction or no related data. Means 'organization 1 ' and 'organization 2 ' no signed data in any week. Can we show that data by 0 | 0 | 0 .. etc.

Comment: @SyedOsama MySQL sadly lacks the generate_series of PostgreSQL but that still is possible. Check out how it's done here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6871220/2115135 Your week generation will be something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea6eb2/6 then you have to left join that table with your business