# MySQL Select First Day of Year and Month

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

How to find first day of year in SELECT?

```
SELECT `DATE`,`SomeValue1`,`SomeValue2`
FROM `SomeTableName`
WHERE (`DATE` >= [...first day of the year in date format...])
```

I found this for month - but I don't QUITE have the grasp enough for year:
(I was looking for this for a separate query to find data between beginning of month and now)

```
WHERE (`DATE` between  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW() )
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you need:

```
WHERE (`DATE` between  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01') AND NOW() )
```

To be honest, you could do:

```
WHERE (`DATE` between  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y') AND NOW() )
```

Answer (score 45):

To get the first day of the current year, I use:

```
SELECT MAKEDATE(year(now()),1);
```

So in your query you would write:

```
where `date` >= MAKEDATE(year(now()),1)
```

I quite commonly do something like a sales report for the past full 2 years, but I always want to start at the beginning of a year.  So shows 2 full years and the year to date.

```
where date>= MAKEDATE(year(now()-interval 2 year),1)
```

But to further complicate it, our financial years starts on the first of May. I always want to start on the first of May.

```
where date >= MAKEDATE(year(now()-interval 2 year),1) + interval 120 day
```

or as an alternative

```
where date >= MAKEDATE(year(now()-interval 2 year),121)
```

The first of May being the 121st day of a the year.  But this method does not work in leap years.

The leap year proof version is:

```
where date => select MAKEDATE(year(now()-interval 5 year),1) + interval 4 month
```

Which will always return a xxxx-05-01 date, whether a leap year or not.

Comment: SELECT MAKEDATE(year(now()),1); Looks cleaner than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

If the above works for the month, then this will work for the year:

```
WHERE (`DATE` between  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01') AND NOW() )
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why but in my case when browsing through 3 mln. records the fastest method is:

```
where `DATE` >= CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-01-01')
```