# In Jaspersoft Studio, how do I use the DATEFORMAT() function?

Tags: jasper-reports

Here's a screenshot:

[Here's a screenshot http://www.coletrumbo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/dateformat-1024x575.png](http://www.coletrumbo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/dateformat-1024x575.png)

I'm trying to turn the current date into July 1st of the current year using DATEFORMAT(). I learned how to do that in MySQL from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412017/mysql-select-first-day-of-year-and-month), and I hoped it would work similarly in Jaspersoft Studio- turns out `date_format( curdate(), '%Y-07-01' )` doesn't translate into

DATEFORMAT( TODAY(), '%Y-07-01' ) or DATEFORMAT( TODAY(), YY/07/01 ). Neither worked.

I could keep trying to get creative and hopefully find something that works, but I'd rather actually understand how to use DATEFORMAT().

I checked the Jaspersoft Studio User Guide, but it's not there. From the prompts on the screen, it makes a lot of sense, but I just can't figure out the "format pattern" that I'm allowed to apply, or even how to correctly write any format pattern at all. Also, this conveniently named question, [DateFormat Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840265/dateformat-pattern), didn't actually help at all. And [community.jaspersoft.com/answers](http://community.jaspersoft.com/answers) is kind of a joke in my opinion. When I checked it a couple days ago, it was filled with spam linking to live hockey games.

Thanks in advance. I'm sure this is a beginner level question, so I feel dumb asking it, and I feel like I'm wasting other people's space and time with it because I should already know. So I really appreciate your willingness to care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the source code for the DateTime functions directly in JR repository: https://sourceforge.net/p/jasperreports/code/ci/master/tree/jasperreports/demo/samples/functions/src/net/sf/jasperreports/functions/standard/DateTimeFunctions.java

As you can see the code is fairly simple and relies on the Joda Time library.
Therefore the second parameter you are trying to enter is a String, while the first one is a Date object.

Indeed something that could work for you is an expression like this DATEFORMAT(TODAY(), "07-01-YYYY")

Regards,
Massimo.

Comment: I'm using Jaspersoft Studio 6.2.0.final.<br/>
If I use the above expression `DATEFORMAT(TODAY(), "07-01-YYYY")` I get the following error: <pre><code>Error while processing request:
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. The method TODAY() is undefined for the type report_1456696467009_468184
                value = DATEFORMAT(TODAY(), "07-01-YYYY"); //$JR_EXPR_ID=13$
</code</pre><br/>
With Studio 6.2.0 I can get the current date and format it with: `new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy.HH.mm").format(new Date())`

Comment: @jgrocha Standard functions like DATEFORMAT were moved outside of jasper core package to `jasperreports-functions`. In order to make it work add this artifact to pom.xml:
`<groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId> <artifactId>jasperreports-functions</artifactId>`

Answer (score 2):

I am using the following to get the todays date in a danish format

> "Dato: "+new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy",new
>   Locale("da", "DK")).format(new Date())