# how to show list of dates of previous month?

Tags: mysql

i want to show complete list of last 30 days 
here is my query:

```
 select Distinct DATE_FORMAT(transactions.transaction_date,'%c-%d-%Y') as transaction_date,sum(amount)as Amount from transactions group by  DATE_FORMAT(transactions.transaction_date,'%c-%d-%Y')
```

and here is my query result:

[image]

but i want

```
transaction_date Amount
1-01-2014         0
2-01-2014         0
```

upto so on how i get the complete result?

Comment: Does `transaction_date` employ the DATE data type? If so, `group by  DATE_FORMAT(transactions.transaction_date,'%c-%d-%Y')` will be identical to (and slower than) `group by transaction_date`. Aside from that, I'm afraid it's unclear what you're asking. Also, IMO, it's best to handle date formatting at the application level. That way the client can choose the format for themselves (or it can be set for their locality).

Comment: but how i show all dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach here is to first write a query that gets the list of dates you want, then use an outer join to associate the transaction amounts for the dates in that range on which there were transactions.

My recommendation is to install [common_schema](https://code.google.com/p/common-schema/) and use the [common_schema.numbers](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/numbers.html) table to generate the date list.

For example you can run a query like this to get the last 30 days (exclusive of today):

```
select (current_date() - interval n day) as day
from common_schema.numbers
where n between 1 and 30
order by day
```

Then you can combine that with your existing query to get the desired result (I made some other small changes to your query to limit it to the relevant date range and to use `DATE()` instead of `DATE_FORMAT()` for the sake of simplicity):

```
select days.day, coalesce(transactions_rollup.total,0)
from
(
  select (current_date() - interval n day) as day
  from common_schema.numbers
  where n between 1 and 30
) days
left outer join (
  select date(transaction_date) as day, sum(amount) as total
  from transactions 
  where transaction_date >= current_date() - interval 30 day
  and transation_date < current_date()
  group by date(transaction_date)
) transactions_rollup on transactions_rollup.day = days.day
order by days.day
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a generator view (similar to the one obtainable by PostgreSQL [generate_series()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-srf.html) function) containing all the dates of the month without gaps. Unfortunately MySQL does not have such a function, so you need to either [pregenerate the dates in some calendar table](http://www.richnetapps.com/using-mysql-generate-daily-sales-reports-filled-gaps/) and then left join your original query to it, or rely on some [big enough table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870499/generate-series-equivalent-in-mysql) for it.

Comment: ...or use a UNION, or handle the logic for missing dates (if that is in fact the problem) at the application level