# How to implement the D'Hondt method to allocate seats to votes in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, voting-system

I have a simple SQL (PostgreSQL or MySQL) table where rows represents parties while a column represents the number of votes they received on an election. I want to allocate the number of seats (n)  to each party (i.e. to a new column) using the [D'Hondt method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D'Hondt_method).

What procedure (or function) should I write to do that?

Update: example for the desired output assumming 4 seats to allocate:

```
           votes    allocated_seats

party1     47000         2
party2     16000         1
party3     15900         1
```

Seats are allocated like that (D'Hondt method):
calculate V/(s+1) for each party
where V: number of votes for the party
      s: seats already allocated to the party

Party with the highest value receives a seat and the process starts over till all the seats are distibuted.

So in the example above:
Seat 1:
party1 47000/(0+1)=47000
party2 16000/(0+1)=16000
party3 15900/(0+1)=15900
party1 receives the seat
Seat 2:
party1 47000/(1+1)=23500
party2 16000/(0+1)=16000
party3 15900/(0+1)=15900
party1 receives the seat
Seat 3:
party1 47000/(2+1)=15666
party2 16000/(0+1)=16000
party3 15900/(0+1)=15900
party2 receives the seat
Seat 4:
party1 47000/(2+1)=15666
party2 16000/(1+1)=8000
party3 15900/(0+1)=15900
party3 receives the seat

Comment: . . If you want an answer to your question, I would recommend that you show sample data and the process for solving it.

Comment: When it comes to writing procedures the DBMS being used makes a **big** difference. So you will need to decide if you want to use MySQL or Postgres

Comment: @GordonLinoff :  You are right. The linked wikipedia page shows a good example.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : That's true. Currently we are using postgresql but there is a chance that we will move to mysql.

Comment: Good luck with that downgrade ;)

Comment: Victor, for the avoidance of doubt: this question is likely to close in its present condition, since there is no implementation attempt around which a concrete question can be posed. Can you give it a go, or search on the web for an existing implementation, and go from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, you don't need a function for that, a simple `update` can do it:

```
update dhont
set    seats = coalesce(calculated.seats, 0)
from   dhont as parties
left join (
  select party, count(*) as seats
  from (
    select     party
    from       dhont
    cross join generate_series(1, :seat_count) as divisor
    order by   cast(votes as decimal) / divisor desc
    limit      :seat_count
  ) as seat_labels
  group by party
) as calculated on parties.party = calculated.party
where parties.party = dhont.party
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e7d62/7)

*Note*: these are sample data. For actual `join` conditions, please use your table's primary key (or at least a unique key), not just the party's name.

In theory, the same can work in [MySQL too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join), but with an ugly [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870499/generate-series-equivalent-in-mysql).

Comment: Thanks, it looks like a simple and elegant solution for my problem!