# Query showing the amount per day just with views

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have these registers in mysql (also in postgresql):

```
Venta   
date        amount
01/02/2015  7
10/02/2015  8
10/02/2015  9
20/03/2015  4
20/03/2015  11
25/04/2015  1
```

So, I would like to make a query where I get the total amount per day and if an amount in the day doesn't exist, display the day with 0. Something like this:

```
date        amount
01/01/2015  0
02/01/2015  0
03/01/2015  0
04/01/2015  0
05/01/2015  0
06/01/2015  0
.  .   .    .
.  .   .    .
01/02/2015  7
.  .   .    .
.  .   .    .
10/02/2015  17
.  .   .    .
.  .   .    .
20/03/2015  15
.  .   .    .
.  .   .    .
25/04/2015  1
.  .   .    .
.  .   .    .
30/12/2015  0
31/12/2015  0
```

How can I make the query without using function? I heard that views are the best way, but I have not idea how to make it.

Comment: You need a table with the dates. Then it's a simple outer join.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this readily in Postgres:

```
select dates.dte, coalesce(sum(v.amount), 0) as amount
from generate_series('2015-01-01'::timestamp, '2015-12-31'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) dates(dte) left join
     venta v
     on v.date = dates.dte
group by dates.dte
order by dates.dte;
```

This is much more cumbersome in MySQL, unless you have a calendar table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you are using generate_series which is a special function from postgresql.. the idea is do it without a function like that

Comment: [Uncle Google could help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870499/generate-series-equivalent-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Create a calender table with all date you need, and do the join.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a table with a list of sequential dates, just define what has been called a number or tally table. It is simply a one-column table of sequential integer values from 1 or 0 on up to some ridiculous limit. This table will then provide a way to sequence through letters of the alphabet or dates in a range or indexes into a varchar or whatever you need.

I call mine Tally and the one field is Num and the values start at zero instead of one.

```
select  t.Num
from    Tally t
where   t.Num between 0 and 6;
```

This supplies seven consecutive values or a week's worth of dates. All you need to do is set the starting point.

```
select  t.Num, StartDate + t.Num DateValue
from    Tally t
where   t.Num between 0 and 6;
```

Now join that with your table and group accordingly.

```
select  StartDate + t.Num VentaDate, Coalesce( Sum( m.Amount ), 0 ) DailyAmount 
from    Tally t
left join MyTable m
    on  m.Venta = StartDate + t.Num
group by StartDate + t.Num
where   t.Num between 0 and 6;
```