# MYSQL -How to set zero if no row in select date

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to select value from given date and same time if no row in that date then it should return 0 in that specific date. here is my query

```
SELECT
    sum(`value`) AS `VALUE`,
    serverTimeStamp AS date
FROM
    table1 t1

WHERE
    serverTimeStamp BETWEEN CONVERT_TZ(
        '2016-03-21 00:00:01',
        '+00:00',
        '-05:30'
    )
AND CONVERT_TZ(
    '2016-03-25 23:30:36',
    '+00:00',
    '-05:30'
)
GROUP BY
    YEAR (date),
    MONTH (date),
    WEEK (date),
    DAY (date)
ORDER BY
    date ASC;
```

Output :

**value date**

```
96 2016-03-21 00:00:01

76 2016-03-23 00:00:01

56 2016-03-25 00:00:01
```

Expected Output :

**value date**

```
96 2016-03-21 00:00:01

0 2016-03-22 00:00:01

76 2016-03-23 00:00:01

0 2016-03-24 00:00:01

56 2016-03-25 00:00:01
```

Any idea to achieve this?

table1 :

```
**id value serverTimeStamp**

 1   96 2016-03-21 00:00:01

  2  76 2016-03-23 00:00:01

 3  56 2016-03-25 00:00:01
```

but what i am expecting in query if there is no row in given date then it should be 0 and specific date like below

**value date**

```
96 2016-03-21 00:00:01

0 2016-03-22 00:00:01

76 2016-03-23 00:00:01

0 2016-03-24 00:00:01

56 2016-03-25 00:00:01
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a table storing your possible dates and then LEFT JOIN your query to it, so that every date that is missing from your query would still be included in the output, but with the value 0.

How to generate data into table with dates: [Generate series equivalent in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870499/generate-series-equivalent-in-mysql)

You just need to alter this query to include an INSERT INTO your table with dates.

Then, depending on how you insert your date (with time - if it's static coming from your query, or without time - if it's changing) you need to join that table with your existing query on the column value if it contains time, or if it doesn't, on the date part extracted from `serverTimeStamp` from your query

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedures and do like below to get your desired output

```
create table temp_data
(
id int,
value int,
server_date datetime 
);

Drop temporary table if exists temp_generate_dates; 
create temporary table temp_generate_dates 
( 
temp_date datetime 
); 

insert into temp_generate_dates 
select adddate('2016-03-21 00:00:01', @num:=@num+1) as date 
from 
temp_data, 
(select @num:=-1) num 
limit 5; 


select coalesce(t1.value,0),t2.temp_date from temp_generate_dates t2 
left join temp_data t1 on t2.temp_date = t1.server_date ;
```

Comment: I am getting "Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY"

Comment: it not works as expecting, it will return only one row when i check 21 to 25 dates.

Comment: please update your table's data & architecture in your question.

Comment: any idea for this?

Comment: Add your Table1,Table2,Table3,Table4 data in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108593/discussion-between-mmmms-and-jordan).