# get 12 month application count form SQL and start count form previous 3 month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This my Table Structure

```
        ###Table                        ###Expected Outpoot

    ID |    create_date                 Month | Application | Year
    ------------------------------      --------------------------
    1  |    2017-06-25 10:00:11         10   |      0       | 2016
    2  |    2017-06-26 10:00:11         11   |      0       | 2016
    3  |    2017-07-02 10:00:11         12   |      0       | 2016
    4  |    2017-07-25 10:00:11         1    |      0       | 2017
    5  |    2017-08-21 10:00:11         2    |      0       | 2017
    6  |    2017-08-22 10:00:11         3    |      0       | 2017
    7  |    2017-08-25 10:00:11         4    |      0       | 2017
                                        5    |      0       | 2017
                                        6    |      2       | 2017
                                        7    |      2       | 2017
                                        8    |      3       | 2017
                                        9    |      0       | 2017
```

I am Trying to get the monthly data count from my table. I want to start the count form Previous 3 month.

#### This is what I have tried so far?

#### Edit: I am close to solve the issue.Here is the query and result.

```
select date_format(tn.create_date,'%Y-%m') as mon,
count(*) as num
FROM table_name as tn
GROUP BY mon order by mon;


Month       |   Application 
--------------------------------
2017-06     |       2       
2017-07     |       2       
2017-08     |       3
```

So, How do i get my expected output?

Here is the [Query Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9rsSfgz7wX7xHYnnRQnp8w/0)

Comment: A good effort, but please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You'll need a numbers table and you need to fix the `group by` (don't use the alias in the group by)

Comment: @Strawberry sir i have edited the question and added sql fiddle if you can help.

Comment: @JohnHC sir i have edited the question and added sql fiddle if you can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a list of months to join into your query. You can make a table for it, as @JohnHC suggested or use [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870499/generate-series-equivalent-in-mysql) to list the months like this:

```
set @start='2017-06-01';

select YEAR(date), MONTH(date), COUNT(create_date) from 
(
    select adddate(@start, INTERVAL @num:=@num+1 MONTH) date
    from test, (select @num:=-9) num
    limit 12
) as dt
LEFT JOIN test ON MONTH(create_date) = MONTH (date) and YEAR(create_date) = YEAR(date)
GROUP BY date;
```

Notice, that in the `dt` query, the actual data from the `test` table is not accessed, but it is required to contain at least 12 rows to work. Also, you don't need to use the same table for generating the month sequence what you use for querying the `create_date`.

You can set the start of the interval in the `@num:=-9` expression. `-9` in this case means 9 months before @start date. You can set the length of the interval in the `LIMIT` clause.

[Example fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pGRLLspGdwYMswXDvkXEXZ/1)

Comment: Why 12 rows required sir at the beginning may be no row available in table. then it would show all zero.

Comment: It is because the join `from test, (select @num:=-1) num`.  The `(select @num:=-1) num` part is a single value. This generates a cartesian product, therefore you need the 12+ row in the table. It is not required to use this table. You can make a brand new table with 12 empty columns, since the data in the table is not used.

Comment: sorry sir but mistakenly i have added next 12 month in my expected result actually i want previous 12 month.  So what to do for that. I have update my question sir.

Comment: I've edited my answer, adding an explanation for how you can manipulate the month sequence.

Comment: i have added my query fiddle in the question in which i have added my latest tried query.

Comment: I think i provided you the full answer. What question do you have yet?

Comment: sorry sir if i may irritate you. I have update the question sir. can you help for that i have added query fiddle.

Comment: You don't irritate me, I just don't know what can I do for you. You can't leave the `dt` subquery. Take another look on the fiddle in my answer.