# How to display all the dates between two dates stored in my table by single query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display all the dates between two dates for a particular record

And this is the table :

```
ID Start_Date  End_Date
-------------------------
1  2013-01-14  2013-01-18
2  2013-02-01  2013-02-04
```

and now i want to get all the dates between from date and to date.

Expected output

```
ID Date
-------------
1  2013-01-14
1  2013-01-15
1  2013-01-16
1  2013-01-17
1  2013-01-18
2  2013-02-01
2  2013-02-02
2  2013-02-03
2  2013-02-04
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: I'd use a calendar table (or cte) storing all needed dates. OUTER JOIN that table.

Comment: Try to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870499/generate-series-equivalent-in-mysql

Comment: Try [generate-days-from-date-range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range)

Comment: @jarlh i can't create any calendar table

Comment: Which MySQL are you using? A recursive cte can create those dates!

Comment: @RadimBača i already tried these solutions

Comment: @jarlh i'm using MySQL 5.7.21

Comment: Too bad, you need a newer version to get cte support. Now you really need that calendar table...

Comment: Is there any other solution with this version of MYSQL?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:: this works on sql server (my bad didn't see the tag). Will probably do for mysql as well as it supports the same date functions

try something like this replacing my hard coded values with your table values. This brings back all days between 2 dates including the start date. If you wish to keep the max date too, you'll have to modify my code

```
create table #datediff
(
id int,
dates date
)

declare @min date, @max date,@df int

set @min = '2018-01-30'
set @max = '2018-02-5'
set @df = DATEDIFF(DAY,@min,@max)


while @df <> 0
begin
    insert into #datediff
    Values ( 1, DATEADD(D,-1,@max))


    set @df = @df -1
    set @max = DATEADD(D,-1,@max)       
end


select * from #datediff

drop table #datediff
```

Comment: it is a temporary table only used to get the results you need (hashtag is for temporary). It does not mess your database's structure

Comment: yes i know but it will get all dated between two dates i want all dates between from date and to date column