# Calculate average for each month for a given date range

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have the *employees* table where each employee has a related *start_date*, *end_date* and a *salary*.

**NOTE:** on the bottom you can find the SQL code to import the structure and data.

```
+----+-------+------------+------------+---------+
| id | name  | start_date | end_date   | salary  |
+----+-------+------------+------------+---------+
|  1 | Mark  | 2017-05-01 | 2020-01-31 | 2000.00 |
|  2 | Tania | 2018-02-01 | 2019-08-31 | 5000.00 |
|  3 | Leo   | 2018-02-01 | 2018-09-30 | 3000.00 |
|  4 | Elsa  | 2018-12-01 | 2020-05-31 | 4000.00 |
+----+-------+------------+------------+---------+
```

### The problem

For a given date range I want to extract the average of the salaries for each month within the given date range.

**UPDATE:** I would like to have the solution for MySQL 5.6 but it would be great to have also the solution for MySQL 8+ (just for personal knowledge).

### Example

If the date range is ***2018-08-01*** - ***2019-01-31***, the SQL statement should loop from August 2018 to January 2019 and it has to calculate the average salary for each month:

- in **August 2018** the active employees are **Mark**, **Tania**, **Leo** (because August 2018 is between their *start_date* and *end_date*) so the average is **3333.33**
- in **September 2018** the active employees are **Mark**, **Tania**, **Leo** (because September 2018 is between their *start_date* and *end_date*) so the average is **3333.33**
- in **October 2018** the active employees are **Mark**, **Tania** so the average is **3500.00**
- in **November 2018** the active employees are **Mark**, **Tania** so the average is **3500.00**
- in **December 2018** the active employees are **Mark**, **Tania**, **Elsa** so the average is **3666.6667**
- in **January 2019** the active employees are **Mark**, **Tania**, **Elsa** so the average is **3666.6667**

Following you can see the expected result for the date range ***2018-08-01*** - ***2019-01-31***

```
+------+-------+------------+
| year | month | avg_salary |
+------+-------+------------+
| 2018 | 08    | 3333.33    |
| 2018 | 09    | 3333.33    |
| 2018 | 10    | 3500.00    |
| 2018 | 11    | 3500.00    |
| 2018 | 12    | 3666.67    |
| 2019 | 01    | 3666.67    |
+------+-------+------------+
```

**NOTE:** I solved this problem mixing MySQL with PHP code but for big date range it has to execute too many queries (one each month). So I would like to have a solution **using MySQL only**.

### SQL to import structure and data

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL,
  `salary` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `employees` (`id`, `name`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `salary`) VALUES
(1, 'Mark', '2017-05-01', '2020-01-31', '2000.00'),
(2, 'Tania', '2018-02-01', '2019-08-31', '5000.00'),
(3, 'Leo', '2018-02-01', '2018-09-30', '3000.00'),
(4, 'Elsa', '2018-12-01', '2020-05-31', '4000.00');
```

Comment: You should probably mention which version, because this kind of thing is considerably simplified in 8.0+

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I would like to have the solution for MySQL 5.6 but it would be perfect to have the solution also for 8+ just for personal knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply type the desired months (or use PHP code to generate them) and join with it:

```
SELECT ym, AVG(salary)
FROM (
    SELECT '2018-08-01' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH AS ym UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-08-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-08-01' + INTERVAL 2 MONTH UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-08-01' + INTERVAL 3 MONTH UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-08-01' + INTERVAL 4 MONTH UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-08-01' + INTERVAL 5 MONTH
) AS yearmonths
JOIN employees ON ym BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
GROUP BY ym
```

If you have a table that contains numbers 0, 1, ... then you can use that. You can even use ***any*** table that has sufficient number of rows:

```
SELECT ym, AVG(salary)
FROM (
    SELECT '2018-08-01' + INTERVAL @n := @n + 1 MONTH AS ym
    FROM anytable, (SELECT @n := -1) x
    LIMIT 100
) AS yearmonths
JOIN employees ON ym BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
WHERE ym <= '2019-01-01'
GROUP BY ym
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a MySQL 8.0 recursive CTE way of doing it. The CTE creates a list of all the `year, month` combinations between the minimum `start_date` and maximum `end_date` in the `employees` table, which is then `LEFT JOIN`ed to the `employees` table to get the average salary for all employees who were working in that particular year and month:

```
WITH RECURSIVE months (year, month) AS
(
  SELECT YEAR(MIN(start_date)) AS year, MONTH(MIN(start_date)) AS month FROM employees
  UNION ALL
  SELECT year + (month = 12), (month % 12) + 1 FROM months
  WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', year, month, '01'), '%Y-%m-%d') <= (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM employees)
)
SELECT m.year, m.month, ROUND(AVG(e.salary), 2) AS avg_salary
FROM months m
LEFT JOIN employees e ON STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', m.year, m.month, '01'), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN e.start_date AND e.end_date
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', m.year, m.month, '01'), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2019-01-31'
GROUP BY m.year, m.month
```

Output:

```
year    month   avg_salary
2018    8       3333.33
2018    9       3333.33
2018    10      3500.00
2018    11      3500.00
2018    12      3666.67
2019    1       3666.67
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f826fc11bddf4a3d753128060d3ea78)

Comment: Is it possible to have the same solution using MySQL 5.6? I apologize if I did not specify before. I just updated the question.Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @Dan Unfortunately MySQL only implemented CTEs in version 8.0. GMB's solution is probably the best for MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 1):

To get this done, you would need to generate a list of days from a date range. This is a frequently asked question on SO, I used the accepted solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range). It uses a simple arithmetic method and can generate wide lists of dates (although performance may suffer).

Then, we just need to JOIN with the original table to compute the average salary at that point of time.

```
select
  year(x.date), 
  month(x.date),
  avg(coalesce(e.salary, 0)) avg_salary
from (
  select a.date 
  from (
      select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a) ) DAY as Date
      from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
      cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
      cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
      cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as d
  ) a
  where a.date between '2018-08-01' and '2019-01-31'
) x left join employees e ON x.date between e.start_date and e.end_date
group by year(x.date), month(x.date)
order by 1, 2
```

**[Demo on DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4HMFASxVFfhRbJpK8aqwJX/0)** :

```
| year(x.date) | month(x.date) | avg_salary  |
| ------------ | ------------- | ----------- |
| 2018         | 8             | 3333.333333 |
| 2018         | 9             | 3333.333333 |
| 2018         | 10            | 3500        |
| 2018         | 11            | 3500        |
| 2018         | 12            | 3666.666667 |
| 2019         | 1             | 3666.666667 |
```

PS : anoter approach would have been to create a calendar table, that stores the list of days, and then just :

```
select
  year(x.date), 
  month(x.date),
  avg(coalesce(e.salary, 0)) avg_salary
from 
  mycalendar x
  left join employees e ON x.date between e.start_date and e.end_date
where x.date between '2018-08-01' and '2019-01-31'
group by year(x.date), month(x.date)
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: ...or just upgrade to 8.0+

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer...

Here's an 'old school' solution, using a table of integers (0-9), but note that this kind of thing is redundant in newer versions of sql...

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
  +---+
  | i |
  +---+
  | 0 |
  | 1 |
  | 2 |
  | 3 |
  | 4 |
  | 5 |
  | 6 |
  | 7 |
  | 8 |
  | 9 |
  +---+

SELECT '2018-08-01' + INTERVAL i2.i * 10 + i1.i MONTH x 
  FROM ints i1
     , ints i2 
 WHERE '2018-08-01' + INTERVAL i2.i * 10 + i1.i MONTH BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2019-01-31';

  +------------+
  | x          |
  +------------+
  | 2018-08-01 |
  | 2018-09-01 |
  | 2018-10-01 |
  | 2018-11-01 |
  | 2018-12-01 |
  | 2019-01-01 |
  +------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a Postgresql way of doing it. It can be converted to a Mysql query by changing the equivalent of `generate_series()` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870499/generate-series-equivalent-in-mysql) and `Extract()` in Mysql

```
WITH cte1 AS
  (SELECT generate_series('2018-08-01', '2019-01-31', '1 month'::interval)::date AS date),
     cte2 AS
  (SELECT id,
          name,
          salary,
          generate_series(start_date, end_date, '1 month'::interval)::date AS date
   FROM employees)
SELECT extract(YEAR
               FROM cte1.date),
       extract(MONTH
               FROM cte1.date),
       avg(salary)
FROM cte1
JOIN cte2 ON extract(MONTH
                     FROM cte1.date)=extract(MONTH
                                             FROM cte2.date)
AND extract(YEAR
            FROM cte1.date)=extract(YEAR
                                    FROM cte2.date)
GROUP BY extract(YEAR
                 FROM cte1.date),
         extract(MONTH
                 FROM cte1.date);
```

Comment: The OP asked for a MySQL solution, not for one using PostgreSQL