# How can I change the value for "WHERE startdate >= date" clause and get data for a range of dates?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am querying a property_table that looks like below, showing between which date to which date the property were active.

```
fid     startdate   enddate
---     ----------  --------
2588727 2019-01-11  2019-05-09
2591038 2019-01-11  2019-01-18
2587420 2019-03-11  2019-04-09
2592269 2019-03-29  2019-03-09
```

`fid` is the flat_id for a house/flat.

I am trying to find out how many flats were active on each day between `2019-03-15` and `2019-04-30` in the below format.

```
Date        active_count
----------   -----------  
2019-03-15  235631
2019-03-16  234545
2019-03-17  234334
2019-03-29  342123
..
..
2019-04-30  344322
```

I am able to find active flats on a single day by using the below query. Please help to find for the entire date range as above.

```
-- Number of flats on '2019-03-20' Date
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM invent_table 
WHERE startdate <= '2019-03-20' 
AND enddate >= '2019-03-20'
```

Comment: update your question and add  a clear data sample  your expected  result and your actual result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-srf.html) you create the series of the days you are interested in, join to the table and group:

```
select d.Date, count(i.fid) active_count
from (
 select generate_series(date '2019-03-15', date '2019-04-30', '1 day') as Date
) d left join invent_table i
on d.Date between i.startdate and i.enddate
group by d.Date
order by d.Date
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=67d50815c754a8ad03f9f08e955f2f56).

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Any idea how it can be done in the MySQL server. Just asking.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870499/generate-series-equivalent-in-mysql

Comment: @BikashBehera . . . This question is about Postgres.  If you have another question about MySQL, then you should ask a *new* question.  Similarly, if you have a question about performance, you can ask a *new* question.  This is a fine answer but performance degrades even for moderately long date ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Are your looking for something like this?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM invent_table 
WHERE startdate >= '2019-03-15' 
AND enddate <= '2019-04-30'
```