# Grouping in 5 minute intervals within a time range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some difficulties with the MySQL commands that I want to do.

I need to generate some graphs obtaining a query in MySQL in intervals, for example, of 5 minutes generating an average of a data with the AVG method.

These are my data.

[image]

How do I group them into results with 5 minute intervals?

I already generated a query:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at)) DIV 300)*300) AS t, site_id, AVG(response_time) as c 
FROM sites_health_metrics 
WHERE site_id = 1 
AND created_at BETWEEN '2021-08-23 20:40:00' AND '2021-08-23 21:40:00' 
GROUP BY t ORDER BY t
```

where I get the following:

[image]

I want my output to be like:

[image]

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: @ysth version 8.0.25

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701444/how-do-i-make-a-row-generator-in-mysql and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870499/generate-series-equivalent-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is work

`` SELECT series.`range` as `range`, COALESCE(dt.average, 0) as average FROM 
(
    SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at)) DIV 300)*300) AS fecha, site_id, AVG(response_time) as average
    FROM sites_health_metrics WHERE site_id = 1 
    AND created_at BETWEEN '2021-08-23 20:40:00' AND '2021-08-23 21:40:00'
    GROUP BY fecha
) dt
    RIGHT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    date_format(date_add('2021-08-23 20:40:00', INTERVAL @num:=@num+300 SECOND), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') `range`
    FROM sites_health_metrics , (select @num:=-300) num LIMIT 
) series
ON series.`range` = dt.fecha
GROUP BY `range` ``

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) DIV 300 t, site_id, AVG(response_time) c
FROM sites_health_metrics a
WHERE site_id = 1 
AND created_at BETWEEN '2021-08-23 20:40:00' AND '2021-08-23 21:40:00'
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) DIV 300, site_id
```

Comment: what's the `, id`?  it doesn't look to me like you changed anything significant other than that

Comment: I need the 5 minute intervals that have no records to appear as well, to appear at 0